# Java как выдать уведомление в трее Windows 10

Tags: java, уведомления

Необходимо выдать уведомление вроде этого [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать подобное на [java](/questions/tagged/java). Если есть костыль только для `Windows` то тоже подойдет

Пробовал [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14119801/6119618), но не получилось

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Пробовал это, но не получилось

Не очень информативно. Вот примерно такой же пример, но максимально упрощённый:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

        java.awt.Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("images/tray.gif");
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image);
        tray.add(trayIcon);
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Test.", "This is a message to test notifications in Windows 10",
                TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    }
}
```

}

Вот снимок экрана после его запуска в среде разработки IntellyJ IDEA, под управлением Java 8, ОС Windows 10:
[image: снимок экрана с результатом выполнения примера программы]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй, вот эту библиотеку [TrayNotification](https://github.com/PlusHaze/TrayNotification), мне кажется это то, что тебе нужно

Comment: не работает. Выдает ошибку. На гитхабе в иссуях написал

Comment: "Выдает ошибку": http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275718/1341148 - The only way to work with JavaFX is to subclass Application or use JFXPanel. Т.е., похоже на то, что Вы пытаетесь использовать средства JavaFX вне его контекста, не запустив само JavaFX-приложение.